# How to validate mobile number based on retrofit response from API?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit2

I have backend api in `node.js` and making android app from it. In android app there are two text boxes and one submit button. After user fill both fields and clicks submit I want to validate if mobile exist already or not. I am using `retrofit2` for api call. Now problem is that api call takes some time to validate mobile and retrofit using async call next code runs first and api response comes later. And I want to display a spinner during api working. But I am not able to do it. Please help with code as I am new to android.
Here is **RegisterActivity.java** file:

```
package com.example.narmail.truck30mint;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.services.UserApi;
import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.services.NetworkStatus;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText registerMobileInput, registerPasswordInput;
    Button registerButton;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public static String existmsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        registerMobileInput = findViewById(R.id.registerMobileInput);
        registerPasswordInput = findViewById(R.id.registerPasswordInput);
        registerButton = findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (NetworkStatus.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
                    if (validate()) {
                        Intent data = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, OtpActivity.class);
                        data.putExtra("mobile", registerMobileInput.getText().toString());
                        data.putExtra("pass", registerPasswordInput.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(data);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please connect to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        if (registerMobileInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mobile number is mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else if (registerMobileInput.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && registerMobileInput.getText().toString().trim().length() != 10) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter correct mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else if (registerMobileInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 10) {
            UserApi.mobileExist(registerMobileInput.getText().toString());

            while (existmsg == null) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                System.out.println("in while loop");
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("just below method called");
            if (existmsg != null && existmsg.equalsIgnoreCase("exist")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mobile number already exist please login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            } else if (existmsg != null && existmsg.equalsIgnoreCase("notExist")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occured plz try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        } else if (registerPasswordInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password is mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else if (registerPasswordInput.getText().toString().trim().length() < 6) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Min 6 chars", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is java model class

```
package com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.models;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class mobileExist {
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Here is Api

```
package com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.services;

import android.util.Log;

import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.interfaces.UserClient;
import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.models.mobileExist;
import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.RegisterActivity;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class UserApi {
    private static String mobile_exist_url = "http://10.0.2.2:3002/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static UserClient apiInterface;
    private static String mobileNoStatus;
    private static String signupStatus;
    private static Retrofit getMobileExist(){
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(mobile_exist_url).callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
    /*activity method start*/
    public static void mobileExist(String mobile){
        apiInterface = UserApi.getMobileExist().create(UserClient.class);
        Call<mobileExist> call = apiInterface.getMobileExist(mobile);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<mobileExist>() {
            @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<mobileExist> call, Response<mobileExist> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("response is successfull");
                    RegisterActivity.existmsg = response.body().getStatus();
                } else {
                    RegisterActivity.existmsg = "error";
                     Log.w("status ",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));
                }
                // Log.w("status ",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));
               // System.out.println("in response is now" + mobileNoStatus);
            }
                @Override
                public void onFailure (Call < mobileExist > call, Throwable t){
                    RegisterActivity.existmsg = "error";
                    Log.v("error", "is", t);
                }
        });
      // return false;
    }
}
```

Here is layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout                                                               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/pleaseRegister"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.386"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.128" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerMobileInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="@string/mobileHintRegister"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.358" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerPasswordInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/passwordHintRegister"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.453"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.653" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.459"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.223" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void mobileExist(String mobile, Context context){
    **Utility.showProgressDialog(context, "Please wait"); **
    apiInterface = UserApi.getMobileExist().create(UserClient.class);
    Call<mobileExist> call = apiInterface.getMobileExist(mobile);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<mobileExist>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<mobileExist> call, Response<mobileExist> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                **Utility.dismissProgressDialog(); **
                System.out.println("response is successfull");
                RegisterActivity.existmsg = response.body().getStatus();
            } else {
                RegisterActivity.existmsg = "error";
                Log.w("status ",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));
            }
            // Log.w("status ",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));
            // System.out.println("in response is now" + mobileNoStatus);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure (Call < mobileExist > call, Throwable t){
            RegisterActivity.existmsg = "error";
            **Utility.dismissProgressDialog(); **
            Log.v("error", "is", t);
        }
    });
}
```

Initiate a progress dialog as soon as the mobile dialog is called and dismiss when you are done with response.

Comment: it also does not work app gone not responding.I think because we are performing task on main thread.Can you tell in detail how we can show progress bar and remove while loop and still working

Answer (score 0):

I have modified you both RegisterActivity and UserApi code. You can use this below code. 
I have added an interface to handle your mobile validation callback

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
   public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ValidateMobile {
    EditText registerMobileInput, registerPasswordInput;
    Button registerButton;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public static String existmsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        registerMobileInput = findViewById(R.id.registerMobileInput);
        registerPasswordInput = findViewById(R.id.registerPasswordInput);
        registerButton = findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (NetworkStatus.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
                    validate();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please connect to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void validate() {
        if (registerMobileInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mobile number is mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (registerMobileInput.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && registerMobileInput.getText().toString().trim().length() != 10) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter correct mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (registerMobileInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 10) {
            UserApi.mobileExist(registerMobileInput.getText().toString());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void startOtp() {
        Intent data = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, OtpActivity.class);
        data.putExtra("mobile", registerMobileInput.getText().toString());
        data.putExtra("pass", registerPasswordInput.getText().toString());
        startActivity(data);
    }

    public void validateAndStartOtp() {
        if (registerPasswordInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password is mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (registerPasswordInput.getText().toString().trim().length() < 6) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Min 6 chars", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            startOtp();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMobileValidateSuccess() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMobileValidateFailed() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mobile number already exist please login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**UserApi.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.interfaces.UserClient;
import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.models.mobileExist;
import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.RegisterActivity;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class UserApi {
    private static String mobile_exist_url = "http://10.0.2.2:3002/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static UserClient apiInterface;
    private static String mobileNoStatus;
    private static String signupStatus;
    private static Retrofit getMobileExist(){
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(mobile_exist_url).callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
    /*activity method start*/
    public static void mobileExist(String mobile, Context mContext){

        // Interface callback
        final ValidateMobile callback = (ValidateMobile) mContext;

        apiInterface = UserApi.getMobileExist().create(UserClient.class);
        Call<mobileExist> call = apiInterface.getMobileExist(mobile);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<mobileExist>() {
            @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<mobileExist> call, Response<mobileExist> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // On success call this callback function   
                    callback.onMobileValidateSuccess();
                    System.out.println("response is successfull");
                } else {
                    // On failure call this callback function
                    callback.onMobileValidateFailed();
                    RegisterActivity.existmsg = "error";
                     Log.w("status ",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));
                }
                // Log.w("status ",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));
               // System.out.println("in response is now" + mobileNoStatus);
            }
                @Override
                public void onFailure (Call < mobileExist > call, Throwable t){
                    callback.onMobileValidateFailed();
                    RegisterActivity.existmsg = "error";
                    Log.v("error", "is", t);
                }
        });
      // return false;
    }
}
```

**ValidateMobile.java**

```
public interface ValidateMobile {
    public void onMobileValidateSuccess();
    public void onMobileValidateFailed();
}
```

Comment: not working it says we can implement interface which is in same class.Cyclic inheritence.

Comment: you can create a new java file and put the interface code in it. and rebuild your project

Comment: I have solved it by passing RegisterActivity context to mobileExist function and then show progress bar on start of function and after Response successfull start new intent and send to otp activity right from within onResponse and hide progress bar

Comment: Cool! But I will still suggest to use interface, as passing context can lead to memory leaks if you have not handled it correctly

Comment: Thanks @arshad for your effort i will try to use this code next time.